# How resource is disposed when registered as services.AddSingleton but initiated with a using block

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dispose

I am using .NET Core 3.1.

I have a simple publish class which purpose is to publish messages to a message broker. All the logic for the message broker is in a separate class library and the publish class itself need somehow to get a connection in order to publish the message, so it looks like that:

```
 public class Publisher : IPublisher
 {
    public void Publish(string subject, PublishMessage message)
    {
        var options = ConnectionFactory.GetDefaultOptions();

        using (var connection = new ConnectionFactory().CreateEncodedConnection(options))
        {
            connection.OnSerialize = jsonSerializer;
            connection.Publish(subject, message);
            connection.Flush();
        }
    }
 }
```

By the way `new ConnectionFactory().CreateEncodedConnection(options)` is native for the message broker so this is not a wrapper written by me.

However. In my web project I register this in the DI like this:

`services.AddSingleton<IPublisher, Publisher>();`

My final goal is to share the same connection, I know that when the times comes the DI will dispose all disposable resources but since I wrap the connection in a using block does it always dispose the connection and create a new one for each message or the DI manages to handle this somehow. And if not, how can I make is to the connection is not created for each message?

Comment: A DI Container does not perform miracles. It only manages what you tell it to. In your case, you tell it to manage a `Publisher`, but management ends with the creation and destruction of `Publisher`. A DI Container won't inspect and intercept and change the class's methods (compiled) Intermediate Language (IL). That would be a scary thought. The DI Container will not change the way your `Publish` method works. As you tell it to create and dispose the connection on each call, that method will do so. A DI Container (fortunately) can't change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`services.AddSingleton<IPublisher, Publisher>();` Create instance of `Publisher` class when application starts, but connection will be created and disposed every time you calls `Publish` method.